# How to evenly texture a flat surface with different sized faces

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to place a seamless cobblestone texture onto a flat curved plane with different sized faces, if I just unwrap the whole object I have to scale the UV way up for it to look the correct size, and then some faces still look stretched.

I think I want each face to cover the whole UV and be on top of eachother, but this will make the different sized faces stretch, and the texture wont line up correctly, is this a case of me having way too little geometery or is there a way to square the faces up without doing it manually?

I aplogise if I have not given a good explanation or if my terminology is poor but I am very new to this and texturing is proving a bit of a headache.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all the faces and select the face that you have correctly unwrapped (probably initial one) so that it will be active:

[image]

Then press <kbd>U</kbd> -> *Follow Active Quads*.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want, maybe try the *UV: UV Squares* addon. First unwrap your mesh, then open the *UV Editor* and in the *N* panel press on the *UV Squares* tab and on the *To Grid By Shape* button:

[image]

Result (now you can scale up, rotate, etc):

[image]